# Why does the InAppBrowser not work with window.open?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to open a website in my Android app using the Cordova InAppBrowser plugin using the following code:

```
<button ng-click="window.open('https://www.facebook.com', '_system');">Open facebook</button>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, what am I doing wrong? I have already checked whether the plugin has been installed, [here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OltEm.png).

Answer (score 4):

You can only use `window.open` for the InAppBrowser if you redefine it as follows:

```
window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
```

Otherwise you need to use the following:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://www.facebook.com', '_system');
```

For more information, consult the documentation, which you can find [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/).